# Why is Safari always prompting for credentials for website behind NGINX?

Tags: nginx, safari

I have a website deployed behind an NGINX proxy, which uses `auth_basic` for authentication:

```
server {
    root /usr/share/nginx;
    listen       80;
    listen  [::]:80;
    server_name  localhost;
    auth_basic "Restricted Content";
    auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/.htpasswd;
    
    ...
}
```

now when I access this website in both Chrome and Firefox, I am asked to authenticate when opening the website the first time, so only once as expected.
When I access this website in Safari however, I am asked to authenticate *every* page I navigate within the website.

N.B. I have a similar setup with Apache2 (using `AuthType Basic`) and that works fine across all browsers, so this seems specific to NGINX.

Comment: Are you able to use a tool like Wireshark to analyze the packets in/out to track if anything unexpected happens?

Comment: @LexLi yes I do have access to Wireshark, however I have no idea what I should be looking for

Comment: Prompts are triggered by response header like `WWW-Authenticate`, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/WWW-Authenticate. Thus, you should first confirm Safari does prompt because of such headers. Then move back to review your nginx rules.

Comment: @LexLi from Safari's Network tab I can see `Www-Authenticate: Basic realm="Restricted Content"`

Comment: "now when I access this website in both Chrome and Firefox, I am asked to authenticate when opening the website the first time, so only once as expected" is also triggered by that header, so no doubt you can see. But what I am asking is to see more packets to confirm you are "asked to authenticate every page I navigate within the website". If such troubleshooting is too much for you, try to hire an experienced consultant. A site like this wouldn't give you a full tutorial.

Comment: Besides, the Network tab is of little use here, as troubleshooting is only meaningful when you see things in and out of nginx, not just on one side. That's why I asked you to use Wireshark.